# onCompleted() method user is null

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Hi I am working with facebook login.

**LandingFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(ConstantMethods.isNetworkAvailable()){
            GetOrCreateFacebookActiveSession(savedInstanceState);
        }
        GetKeyHash();

    }
```

//button click listener

```
faceBookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new onFacebookLoginListener());
```

**//onFacebookLoginListener()**

// facebook login
private class onFacebookLoginListener implements OnClickListener {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (ConstantMethods.isNetworkAvailable()) {


                hideKeyBoard();
                FacebookLoginUtility utility = new FacebookLoginUtility(getActivity());

                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (!session.isOpened()) {
                    new FacebookLoginUtility(getActivity(),LandingFragment.this).loginToFacebook(getActivity());
                } else {
                    utility.fetch_User_Data(getActivity());
                }



    } else {
        ConstantMethods.showErrorDialog(getActivity(), getResources()
                .getString(R.string.network_conn_loss));
    }

}
}
```

**FacebookLoginUtility.java** // just a class not an Activity

Here I copied all the stuff whatever I have implemented in this class.

```
public class FacebookLoginUtility {

    private Context mContext;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback;
    public static GraphUser FBuser;
    private LandingFragment mLandingFragment;

    public FacebookLoginUtility(Context mContext) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public FacebookLoginUtility(Context mContext,
            LandingFragment landingFragment) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mLandingFragment = landingFragment;
    }

    public void loginToFacebook(Context context) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            // if session is in exceptional state
            if (session.getState() == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED
                    || session.getState() == SessionState.OPENING) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }

            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                String[] PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ = { "email", "user_birthday" };
                List<String> PERMISSION_LIST = Arrays
                        .asList(PERMISSION_ARRAY_READ);
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context)
                        .setPermissions(PERMISSION_LIST).setCallback(
                                statusCallback));
            } else {
                Session.openActiveSession((Activity) context, true,
                        statusCallback);
            }
        } else {

            // showAlertDialog("Please check your internet connection!");
        }
    }

    public void fetch_User_Data(final Context mContext) {

        // request a new session with read permissions if session is opened with
        // publish permissions
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        try {
            if (!isSubsetOf(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"),
                    permissions)) {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        (Activity) mContext, Arrays.asList("email",
                                "user_birthday"));
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Upgraded
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("" + user);
                if (user != null) {
                    FBuser = user;
                    mLandingFragment.getFacebookUserDetails(user
                            .getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                    /*
                     * setRegisterValuesUsingFacebook(user.getInnerJSONObject()
                     * .toString());
                     */
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unable to get user profile data",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // return activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;

        return (activeNetworkInfo != null)
                && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    public static boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
            Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

In this class the onCompleted() method,the user object gets null value. So that I can't get the user details.

From the above explanation,

1. I am trying to login from Fragment
2. I wrote separate class for login. Because I need to reuse this in some other page of my app.(Login options given in multiple pages of app).

How could I get the user details ?

Comment: The fetch_user_data() never called. So that the session always closed.

Comment: The fetch_user_data() is only called from your click listener on the LoginButton? Is this the LoginButton from the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @MingLi No.This is customized button.

Comment: are you overriding the onActivityResult method in your Activity or Fragment (that's doing the login) and passing the result over to the active session?

Comment: No I didn't use that... is it mandatory.... ?

Comment: Without it, the SDK wouldn't get the result from the open request. Please see the login tutorial on the Facebook developer website - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2 You can call the onActivityResult method on the UiLifecycleHelper class, or on Session.getActiveSession directly.

Comment: @ming li I will try with that and let you know

Comment: @MingLi Hi, Its working by using onActivityResult method. But in my code I can get GraphUser object value (at onCompleted method) only at secod click of custom facebook button. Could u pls come to chat room?

Comment: Well, it's only working on second click because you're only calling it from the onClick listener. You can also try to call it from your session status callback.

Comment: @MingLi could you explain in detail.

Comment: @MingLi You mean at onActivityResult() method?

Comment: From what I can see in the code that you posted, you're only calling utility.fetch_User_Data from your onClick method. So, the first click will open the session (since one isn't open yet), and the second click will fetch the data.